# Flutter Web shared_preferences and Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-web

When I try to use the `shared_preferences` locally for the web it works.  When I publish the code to `Firebase` it returns the following error:

> main.dart.js:23921 MissingPluginException(No implementation found for
> method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)

I have a button like this:

```
onPressed: ((() async {
    try {
      myData = !myData;
      var preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      preferences.setBool('myData', myData);
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  })),
  icon: const Icon(Icons.question_mark),
  label: const Text('No work firebase'),
)
```

When running it locally for the web it works perfectly! When I deploy it to Firebase I get the error above.

If you care I am running the following commands to deploy:

```
flutter build web
firebase deploy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it most likely was an issue with Flutter.  After upgrading to Flutter `3.3.4` from `3.3.3` and deploying again it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else having this issue and the accepted answer not solving it.
I found that building for web with html renderer solved the issue!

> flutter build web --web-renderer html

Comment: Any knowledge on why this is the case would be greatly appreciated!